# What is the most accurate method for timing beats of a rhythm game in Haxe (NME)?

Tags: audio, time, haxe, nme

I am attempting to create a side scrolling shooter prototype in which the actions of the enemies and bullets are timed to a beat. The target bpm I am working towards is 120.

At the centre of this is obviously the timing of the sounds and I have begun by trying to create a metronome as a guide. I use the getTimer function to calculate the frame time and accumulate this value until it reaches the right time (500ms for 120bpm), then playing a sound.

As you can imagine, this doesn't give a constant result and suggests that's there is a better option. So my question is what is the most accurate method to time sounds for a game of this type? Is this a problem solely with the timing? I am using Haxe NME, could i be too far removed from the audio device to play sounds fast enough?

Comment: Threads? Have a thread execute as fast as it can and keep track of the time that way? Main thread will then trigger from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing a `Sound` will have different behavior on the different NME platforms, including different latencies. Even in plain old Flash, `Sound.play` and `SoundChannel.position` aren't very accurate!

For a rhythm game, you really do need low-level audio control, which NME doesn't currently have. If you are targeting Flash, you can use [`SampleDataEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html) to dynamically mix the audio and get more accurate timing. There are plans to add cross-platform support for `SampleDataEvent` to NME in the future ([source](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike. Yes this was the method I used in the end, but as you said I was disappointed that it was only for Flash. Nice to know they are thinking of a cross platform solution.